# Change SSRS Report Column width and Height based on Excel Units?

Tags: excel, reporting-services

I have a criteria where the column width and height should be based on Excel Column Height and width

If I go to Excel and Check    Row Height - 12.75

```
                                         Column Width - 28
```

How to set up the Height and width of the column in INCHES in SSRS REPORT based on above values?

Is Excel measured as UNITS?  If so do we have a conversion tool to identify?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Excel measurements are in Points.  You can specify SSRS measurements in points e.g. 12.75pt.  The doco recommends using whole points.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd255234.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The absolute value (default) in Excel for height is in units of points and for column width is in number of characters