# Large white space next to last column in ssrs 2012 report while exporting to Excel

Tags: excel, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have a SSRS 2012 report which has two different datasets which needs to exported into two worksheets in the same Excel file.One dataset has 10 columns to be exported to excel and other has only 4 columns.

So I have inserted two tablixes in design surface and configured one dataset to first tablix and another dataset to second tablix. Then in properties of each tablix, I have set Options in PageBreak section as BreakLocation to END, Disabled to False and ResetPageNumber to False. Tablixes are placed below one another in the report design surface as shown in the screenshot 1 without any space between them.

[Screenshot : 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Upxv8.jpg)

When I try to export report in excel format, the data from two datsets are exported in the different worksheets in same excel as expected. But the problem is, the column next to last column is too large than the default excel column width for the worksheet which is having 4 columns. Please find the screenshot : 2 .

[Screenshot : 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WRx5D.jpg)

In simple words, while exporting to excel, a long white/blank space is available next to the last column for tablix 1 due to its alignment in design surface

Is there a way to format that column to default size

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23506501/change-ssrs-report-column-width-and-height-based-on-excel-units

Comment: I never got this problem before but please try  1. Set Report properties ConsumeContainWhiteSpace = True 2.put Tablix2 into Rectangle [Make Rectangle as parent Element of Tablix2] )

Comment: I have tried your suggestion. Still I am getting the large white space right to last column in excel file while rendering. I guess, it is due to white space (design Surface) next to the tablix 2 (highlighted in red in screenshot : 1 above).Any other work around please?